# Trying to store multiple copies of variables to use in calculation further

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I am fetching a response from API. It is an array of objects. I am looping through the array and if a condition is true at each element, I am storing 1 property of that object(element) in a variable(inside the foreach loop). By the end of the array, I will have 5 properties that will be stored. I want to have separate copies of those values, because I am using them to calculate for 5 different days.

```
foreach(var item in weather.list)
{
    if(currentDateTime.Hour == 6)
    {
        windDegrees = item.wind.deg;
    }

}
```

After I am done, there should be 5 windDegrees. I should be able to use each one of those 5 separately, and calculate airplane traffic data for 5 separate days.

Comment: use `ArrayList` or `List<T>` to store just the data. Or if you want to store the data along with some reference, use `Dictionary` or `HashTable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store them to a new list.

```
List<object> windDegreesList = new List<object>();
foreach(var item in weather.list)
{
    if(currentDateTime.Hour == 6)
    {
        windDegrees = item.wind.deg;
        windDegreesList.Add(item.wind.deg);
    }

}
```